# Yet another llame "STOP! Look and Listen"

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-review-audits, flag-ban

I clicked on "add comment", because I wanted to add some thougts to the question. The result?
[image]

Well, listen to what? Commenting is a review failure? Why leave the "add comment"-option open then? The question is here -> [Why is it an "exc_bad_access" and not a "run-time" or "compile-time" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570793/why-is-it-an-exc-bad-access-and-not-a-run-time-or-compile-time-error)

There are still too many mysterious "ehh what?" in the review-system. I have passed test after test, dozens successful in a row, but after this one single "fail" I am banned for reviewing again. Again? What is this system anyway? A game of killing motivation?

And still, I need some kind of explanation why I am banned from asking questions on http://meta.stackexchange.com. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans is not very helpful.

Comment: As for your question ban on Meta Stack Exchange, you may want to take a look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179093/get-rid-of-the-question-ban-on-meta-suspend-actively-harmful-users-manually

Comment: @Antony, yeah, thanks - but the question is not answered there either. Just a whole lot of people that agrees in the illogical.

Comment: @Antony, OK. But still I cannot figure out why I am banned. If it really is true, that "_you can get question blocked on Meta simply for asking questions that aren't popular with the Meta crowd_" then it is worser than I thought.

Comment: I guess you have figured it out then. I don't like this either, but there isn't much we can do. Maybe you should try answering on Meta while you still can, since there isn't much hope of improving a meta post that is unpopular, rather than of low quality.

Comment: And the downvotes to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229303/got-the-marshal-badge-too-easy should clear the topic?

Comment: @Antony, I have two questions with negative score. One with -12, -11 for some minutes ago, and one with -1. It does not make sense.

Comment: You've got a -20 and a -23 as well, still seems harsh to be banned, got deleted posts?